# Edit icon VS Edit CTA while redirecting the user to a different screen?

Tags: buttons, ux-field, inline-edit, edit

I need to redirect the user to a form which is on a different page after he clicks edit. So what is the best practise here, to use the pencil icon or edit button or anything else where it is clear that the user will be redirected to a different screen without getting surprised

Answer (score 0):

It's depends, I think the question should be: Who's your user?
If a heavy user from internet a pencil icon could be enough, but if your user is a old person, edit button can be a good thing.

For me: Try to prototipate your decision, and make some usability tests with your users.

Comment: Alright, Thank you! The target group is mid age enterprise people. So giving an icon and then re directing them to a different page will be a good experience??

Comment: @shwetasinwal make a test with them, do you already have an interface or prototipe?

Answer (score 0):

Both. If you have to choose, use text.

Icons are quicker when searching for a button in an interface if the user remembers what to look for, but can often be unclear as it can be interpreted in different ways.
Text is always a lot clearer but takes slightly more time to find the button in an interface. I personally think this is negligible and text labels make an interface much easier to use for new users.